# Streamlining PHP Concatenation with Conditional Statements

Tags: php, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a string in PHP which is a verified tick badge, but I need to include a conditional statement inside the concatenation. Here's the code I have so far:

```
<?php if($data->verified): ?>
  <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
<?php endif;?>
```

---

fetching comments data:

```
while($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $content .= '

    <div class="caption animated fadeIn">
            <a href="profile/' . $data->username . '"><img src="' . self::display_image(AVATARS_THUMBS_ROUTE . $data->avatar) . '" class="img-circle dashboard-avatar" alt="Avatar"/></a> <a href="profile/' . $data->username . '">' . $data->name . '</a><span>' . Messages::generate_emoticons(User::generate_links($data->content)) . '</span>
    </div>
    ';
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? (now you display a fa-check-circle instead of a fa-verified)

Comment: are you getting errors or i think u r getting blank page

Comment: then put the `<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>` into a var (like $css) and concatanate it like the rest to $content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put the HTML in a variable, make it empty when you need, and concatenate it like you do with the rest:

```
while($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if($data->verified) {
        $icon = '<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>';
    } else {
        $icon = '';
    }
    $content .= '

    <div class="caption animated fadeIn">
            <a href="profile/' . $data->username . '">'.$icon.'<img src="' . self::display_image(AVATARS_THUMBS_ROUTE . $data->avatar) . '" class="img-circle dashboard-avatar" alt="Avatar"/></a> <a href="profile/' . $data->username . '">' . $data->name . '</a><span>' . Messages::generate_emoticons(User::generate_links($data->content)) . '</span>
    </div>
    ';
}
```